# What's up with input on Linux 5.3?

Tags: linux, keyboard, performance, mouse, input

I recently upgraded to Linux 5.3, and had a problem which significantly impacted usability: during some disk I/O spikes, mouse movements, and sometimes keystrokes, wouldn't register, so I couldn't do anything for several—or even many—seconds at a time.

I'm pretty sure it's an input problem, rather than just the screen not being updated. In the latter case, I'd expect the cursor to jump to where it should be once the spike ended, but that wasn't happening; it was as if I wasn't moving the mouse at all.

I went back to the 5.2 branch and am not having this problem at all now, so I assume something changed at 5.3 to cause this. Just to be sure, I've been running for quite a while under both 5.2 and 5.3 kernels. I also rebuilt the 5.2 kernel with the new version of GCC I installed after the 5.2, but it has made no difference to the result.

EDIT: I've been running `evtest` on the appropriate device for the mouse, while running a 5.3 kernel. Whenever this problem occurs, I make plenty of mouse movements, and then check the output. After trying for a long time, I finally caught some "SYN_DROPPED" events, which appear after small delays (from a fraction of a second to a couple of seconds after the previous event).

System information:

- Distro: Gentoo
- I build kernels with my own configuration.
- Root filesystem is Btrfs with about 3.3 TiB of data, if that's important.
- Using X.org server.

Let me know any other information I should post.

Comment: Are both 5.2 (working fine) and 5.3 (has the problem) the same configuration?

Comment: As nearly as practical. I ran `make oldconfig` as I usually do.

Comment: Does evtest behave abnormally? How do you ensure this is kernel problem

Comment: Start by building the some kernel as you currently have, and test it. (test first)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Just what do you mean by the same as I currently have, and by testing? Would you mean kselftest, perhaps??

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I've been comparing 5.2 and 5.3 kernels. Both 5.3.x versions I've tried display the problem during heavy disk I/O, while I haven't seen it even once under 5.2. I also rebuilt the 5.2 with the new version of GCC I installed before building 5.3, on the off-chance that had something to do with it, but no, 5.2 is still fine. As for evtest, I don't know what to look for that would be abnormal; shows button presses, but not movements, and that's all I can tell.

Comment: Then it means kernel didn't get the event of mouse moving

Comment: Even though I have no problem moving the cursor?? Oh wait, I was looking at the wrong device (there are apparently 3 of them for this particular mouse). With the right one, I do see movement events as well.

Comment: Still seeing this problem with 5.3.7 and not with 5.2.20.